# Responding to old recruiter message caused me to be part of their company

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

Yesterday I noticed that I had an old (almost two years) recruiter message in my SO Jobs inbox that I never marked as interested/not interested. So I clicked "not interested".

But apparently I actually got a job as a recruiter at that company in the meantime

[image: screenshot of the message as described below]

- The response says that I work at XXX GmbH (the company of the recruiter who originally sent the message)
- I'm being told that SO has let Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe (a.k.a. me) know that I'm not interested
- I received an email letting me know that

  > Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe is not interested in your message
- My own response also ended up in my global inbox (with "balpha", my username, as the sender and with no text):

  [image: screenshot of my inbox]

Comment: Can you let us know if you receive a paycheck at the end of the month? :D

Comment: @Tom Excellent point, maybe I shoudn't complain...

Comment: @balpha You'll be pleased to hear that the Messaging code is just as much of a nightmare as the last time you saw it. I suspect what's happened is, the recruiter no longer has a Talent account so it's just sent it to the only other person in the thread, Benjamin Dumke-von der Ehe (a.k.a. you)

Comment: i'll have a more thorough look in a minute

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I'm pretty sure I never actually looked at it, so it's all good. Also, fancy Staff badge you have there

Comment: @balpha I suspect whoever wrote it initially had their eyes closed too

Comment: Congratulations! :-D

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this! Some other stuff came up but I have a fix which should go out tomorrow

Comment: That is a verrrrrry long day, spanning lots of days and nights. :(